# Oracle SQL to get store branch and product category with maximum sales for branch

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a schema for a store with multiple branches. I'm trying to get a list of branches and their one highest selling product category.

[ERD design for the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfjgt.png)

This is as far as I've gotten with the query:

```
select branch_name,prod_category,sum(p.prod_price*il.inv_line_qty) as 
Category_Value
from w_branches b
 inner join w_products p on p.branch_id= b.branch_id
 inner join w_inv_line il on il.prod_id= p.prod_id
 inner join w_invoices i on i.inv_id=il.inv_id
group by p.branch_id, b.branch_name,p.prod_category;
```

That returns a list of branch names, with each product category that the branch has and the total sales for the category.

```
BRANCH_NAME      PRODUCT CATEGORY        TOTAL SALES
---------------- ------------------------------------
BRANCHMALL       CPU                     41808
BRANCH_POS       Desktop                 62282
BRANCH_EAST      CPU                     51510
BRANCH_EAST      Networking              81600
BRANCH_POS       CPU                     22477
BRANCH_CENTRAL   Desktop                 126066
BRANCHMALL       SSD                     93154
BRANCH_NORTH     CPU                     217685
```

As you can see the branches are repeating. I'd like to get just the category with the maximum sales for the branch, as below.

```
BRANCH_NAME      PRODUCT CATEGORY        TOTAL SALES
---------------- ------------------------------------
BRANCH_POS       Desktop                 62282
BRANCH_EAST      Networking              81600
BRANCH_CENTRAL   Desktop                 126066
BRANCHMALL       SSD                     93154
BRANCH_NORTH     CPU                     217685
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add the solution to your question. Solutions go in answers. Since your question is a duplicate, you can't answer it, so you can answer the duplicate instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can use rank() in oracle to identify the rank and then select all the values with one rank.

```
select * from (
select branch_name, prod_category,category_value, rank() over (partition by branch_name order by category_value desc) as rank from
(select branch_name,prod_category,sum(p.prod_price*il.inv_line_qty) as 
Category_Value
from w_branches b
 inner join w_products p on p.branch_id= b.branch_id
 inner join w_inv_line il on il.prod_id= p.prod_id
 inner join w_invoices i on i.inv_id=il.inv_id
group by p.branch_id, b.branch_name,p.prod_category))
where rank = 1)
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer! Unfortunately I'm getting an error on the last line " where rank=1" that I can't figure out. "Error at Command Line : 10 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "RANK": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier""

Comment: It appears that you should rewrite the last two lines. Instead of "p.prod_category) where rank = 1)" try with "p.prod_category)) where rank = 1" (i.e. bracket should be closed on a different place).

Comment: That resolved it. Thanks so much Pirate & Littlefoot (sounds like you two could be crewmates)!

Comment: I forget that one bracket, Thanks @Littlefoot. Welcome :)

Comment: You're the man Pirate!